# django admin template overriding not working

Tags: django, django-templates, overriding

I want to override `templates/admin/change_form.html` in my own django module `app1`, so following the standard, i added file `change_form.html` with following content to `app1->templates->admin`

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n static %}
{% block object-tools %}
    <h3>My extended html</h3> => Not rendered until => change_form_template = 'admin/change_form1.html'
    {{ block.super }}
    <script defer="defer" src="{% static 'app1/image_preview.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

admin.py (I can achieve it by changing every admin and add giving `change_form_template = 'admin/change_form1.html'` but that is not the way i need it)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Model1
class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # change_form_template = 'admin/change_form1.html' #overriding does not affect, but this does
    pass
admin.site.register(Model1, Model1Admin)
```

**Expected output**: `<h3>My extended html</h3>` should be the part of every `change_form.html` because I have extended `admin/chamge_form.html` without doing anything else anywhere while `app1` exists in project and installed app in `settings.py`

---

Complete steps (I have Django installed in default python of my system)

1. django-admin startproject pr1
2. cd pr1
3. django-admin startapp app1
4. edited settings.py to append a line => `INSTALLED_APPS += ['app1']`
5. Added chnage_form.html to app1/templates/admin
6. Made migrations, created superuser, logged in and opened http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app2/model1/add/

Complete code
https://github.com/humblesami/django-templates

**Edit: Chatgpt answer**

[image]

This does not work either, you check my github code.
Also I have tried to add templates/admin in root directory of project, but nothing appears in rendered change_form.html

Comment: Why is this `change_form_template = 'admin/change_form1.html'` not the way you need it? What was the output instead of your expected output after trying "your" solution?

Comment: Because it does not affect the default/global change_form.html. I do not want me/user who is using my django app to need to have own template and mention in each modeladmin to have some extra feature in every change_form.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your template to

```
app1/templates/admin/change_form.html
```

as

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n static %}
{% block object-tools %}
    <h2>Preivew</h2>
    {{ block.super }}
    <script defer="defer" src="{% static 'app1/image_preview.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Now the mistake/problem in my code/process was adding `app1` to the end of apps list in `settings.py` which did not work but it must be added before `'django.contrib.admin'` so `app1/templates/admin/change_form.html` will be executed after the original `admin/change_form.html`, so customization/updates in html will appear.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + ['app1'] //does not work
//but
INSTALLED_APPS = ['app1'] + INSTALLED_APPS //works
```